# Showing the cardinality of a bounded shape in the xy plane?

Tags: proof-verification, cardinals

I am trying to show that the cardinality of the space between $x^2+y^2<1$ and $x+y>1$ is the same as the cardinality of real numbers

I haven't a clue where do begin with something like this. I have never worked with a space like this. Could someone lead me on the right direction please?

Comment: Are you aware that the plane has the same cardinality as the real line?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that. How do I relate this fact to the shaded semi-circle which the equations bound?

Comment: It's easy to find an injective function from the real line into your shape. Since the inclusion map from your shape to the plane is clearly an injection, you can simply apply the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I'm having trouble with this process. Could Cantor-Bernstein Theorem be used instead of Schroder-Bernstein?

Comment: They are the same theorem. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape is a circle with the diamond in the center removed. Clearly, there exists a short line segment lying in this shape. There is an injective function from the real line into this little line segment. She shape is shown in blue here, and the little line segment is in red.

[image]

Let $A$ be the blue shape, and let the function $h:A\to\mathbb R^2$ be the inclusion function, $h(x)=x$. Since $\mathbb R^2$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$, there is a bijection $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. Thus, $f\circ h$ is an injective function from $A$ to $\mathbb R$.

Since we have injective functions from $A$ to $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ to $A$, we can apply the Schroder-Bernstein (or Cantor-Bernstein) theorem to see that $\mathbb R$ and $A$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: I had drawn the shape with the shaded region only being the one where you have the red line segment. Wouldn't it just be this segment because x+y>1 ?

Comment: Ha! I just barely answered it.